# Step in proof that product of compact spaces is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Many proofs of the fact that the product of compact spaces use the tube lemma, and therefore start somewhat like this:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact spaces. Then for each $x\in X$, $\{x\}\times Y$ can be covered by finitely many open sets.
Why is this true? I understand intuitively but am having a hard time rigorously justifying this.

Comment: Let O be open in X and U be open in Y. Then O X U is open in X x Y. Now Y can be covered by finitely many sets W because it is compact. Let x in O an open set in X. Then {x} X Y can be covered by a finitely many O X W.

Comment: For proof: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff's_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Consider how the topology of $\{x\}\times Y$ is defined, and you will see that $f(p)=(x,p)$, for $p\in Y,$ is a homeomorphism from $Y$ to $\{x\}\times Y.$ Compactness is a topological property, that is, it is preserved by homeomorphism. And $Y$ is compact, so $\{x\}\times Y$ is compact.

Answer (score 0):

The subspace $\{x\}\times Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y$, which is compact by assumption. Compactness is a topological property, meaning if $X\cong Y$ and $X$ is compact, then $Y$ is compact as well.